# MySQL and Java - throwing exception when inserting into the table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am new MySQL user trying to write program that manipulates database through Java.

Have table named `users` with the following attributes `| USERNAME | EMAIL | ROLE |`, where  `USERNAME` is `PRIMARY KEY` and rest of the attributes are `NOT NULL`.

Lets say I do `INSERT INTO users`, since there is Primary Key constrain on `USERNAME` MySQL should throw error. How this error will be throw and how do I catch it within JAVA ? Do I need to write Stored procedure for throwing errors or `INSERT INTO` statement has this capability as well?

Comment: Why don't you first try to follow one of many tutorials on this topic and ask a question when you encounter a specific problem you can't solve? As a hint, I would use a `PreparedStatement` instead of a `Statement`.

Comment: I Googled `mysql insert from java` and on the first page of results I found a good prepared statement example [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement). Downside: its exception handling is terrible. The first hit with decent exception handling is [here](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqljava/). Between the two you'll figure it out. Finally, MySQL will throw when appropriate; you don't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the primary key is violated an `SQLException` will be thrown with a message containing the name of the constraint that was violated. Your exception handling can look something like this:

```
try {
    //do the insert
} catch (SQLException e) {
    if(e.getMessage().contains("MY_CONSTRAINT_NAME")) {
        //duplicate key
    } else {
        //some other error
    }
}
```

An alternative is to check `SQLException.getSQLState()` or `SQLException.getErrorCode()`.

I would recommend using [Spring JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) which takes care of [SQLException translation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-SQLExceptionTranslator) and generally reduces the amount of JDBC codeyou need to write.